# single jquery autocomplete for multiple form dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

how can i use a single jquery autocomplete for multiple form dropdown?

here is my view page(header):

```
$("#full_name").autocomplete({
   source: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/get_names');?>"
});  

$("#department").autocomplete({
   source: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/get_dept');?>"
});  

*** and other like these for subjects, zip and country.
```

controller page:

```
public function get_names(){
 $this->load->model('autocomplete_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
    $this->autocomplete_model->get_fullnames($q);
 }
}  
*** and other functions...
```

model page:

```
function get_fullnames($q)
{
$match = $q;
$this->db->select('full_name');
$this->db->like('full_name', $match,'after');
$query = $this->db->get('employee_list');

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['full_name'])); 
        }
        echo json_encode($row_set); 
    }

}
```

how can i implement a single search term that could be used for multiple criteria?
thank you guys in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to scale; as your database tables grow, this implementation will become very sluggish. What you need to do is use an indexing engine to allow [Full Text Searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search).

MySQL does not allow Full Text Search on InnoDB tables (actually, it was just released in the latest version, but it's still in it's infancy). Look into using [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Poke around StackOverflow to find the best engine for you - there are many helpful questions that have been asked in the past regarding this problem. Hopefully that sets you on the right course.